# show custom data on magento product detail page via module or observer

Tags: module, extensions

i am new to magento i want to show some custom data via module / observer in product details description tab ,

can u please i got some links but i do not want to modify core files can u please guide of hint way of doing it

i created module and added below code:

```
<blocks>        
    <rewrite>
        <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/descriptionfff.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
        </block>
        </reference>
    </rewrite>
</blocks>
```

Comment: are you need to add custom tab on details page or add custom data in exiting tabs?

Comment: ok fine say if i want to add custom data to existing tabs how can i do it via module say i want to override content of desciption.phtml with my custom data

Comment: custom data  fixed ???

Comment: no dynamic data from backend

Comment: have you created product attribute or mange custom table with product relation?

Comment: i will show attributes and some custom data with custome design and all

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the module block config with the layout declaration.

I'm assuming you are very new to magento so a detailed answer covering all module creation and configuration will be too much, so i leave here some links with the basis:

[Alan Storm Guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-1.html)

[How to add a Custom Block](http://www.gpmd.co.uk/blog/beginners-guide-to-setting-up-a-basic-custom-block-module-in-magento/)

I know that Magento SE discourage this kind of "link based" answers but IMO is right for this case.